# codeigniter base_url change from controller

Tags: codeigniter

Is there any way to set my `base_url()` from my controller's ?

OR Can I set my `base_url` `Dynamic` ?

How can I achieved this ?

Comment: Dynamic based on what? Why can't you use a different variable all together in your controller? `$CONTROLLER_BASEURL = '/something';`

Comment: Actually i already used base_url() from my whole site. it is so easy for me if i can change my base url in my controller...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After Searching i found the solution .
yes we can change the base_url from our controller as

```
$this->config->set_item('base_url','http://example.com/xyz') ;
```

Ref: [User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html)

May this answer should help some one .

Comment: is the scope limited to the controller only or will this change the base_url for the entire app?

Comment: limited to specific controller .

Comment: Good solution where domainB.com is allowed, but all links should point to locations on domainA.com (used as main domain, domainB might be project specific)

Answer (score 2):

The base url is set in your config file, so you can update the $config variable from your controllers before you call `base_url()`.

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/60181/

**EDIT**

Of course, I haven't tested this, so don't know if the overwrite will actually work as expected.

You could always extend the url helper with your own class and override the base_url method.

Comment: thanx swatkins . i found the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

OK, so this was fun, but it might not work right and/or break all kinds of other stuff. But, if you make these changes in the relevant files, you can have multiple base url config settings in the config file like so:

```
$config['base_url']['default']  = 'http://firstbase.xyz';
$config['base_url']['otherbase']    = 'http://secondbase.xyz';
```

which can be called like `base_url('','default');//produces http://firstbase.xyz`.

It seems much easier/better to use `$this->config->set_item('base_url','http://abc.com/xyz') ;` as you found in the docs.

---

system/helpers/url_helper.php : line ~63

```
if ( ! function_exists('base_url'))
{
    function base_url($uri = '',$index='')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->config->base_url($uri,$index);
    }
}
```

---

system/core/Config.php

> line ~66

```
$this->set_item('base_url', $index);
```

> line ~175

```
function item($item, $index = '')
{
    if ($index == '')
    {
        if ( ! isset($this->config[$item]))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $pref = $this->config[$item];
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! isset($this->config[$index]))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if ( ! isset($this->config[$index][$item]))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $pref = $this->config[$index][$item];
    }

    return $pref;
}
```

> line ~214

```
function slash_item($item,$index)
{
    if ( ! isset($this->config[$item][$index]))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if( trim($this->config[$item][$index]) == '')
    {
        return '';
    }
    return rtrim($this->config[$item][$index], '/').'/';
}
```

> line ~265

```
function base_url($uri = '',$index='')
{
    return $this->slash_item('base_url',$index).ltrim($this->_uri_string($uri),'/');
}
```

> line ~332

```
function set_item($item, $value, $index)
{
    $this->config[$item][$index] = $value;
}
```

Comment: WaOoo ... thanks stormdrain. Next time when i will start any project then i will use this config... thanx again :-) 
cheers...